# why does phpmailer class echo texts?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

when i send email it echo many unnecessary texts, i don't want these text to be printed out. how can i disable these text.

example:

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 mx.google.com ESMTP p1sm1037082ybn.17
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] 250-SIZE 35651584 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH 250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.0 OK p1sm1037082ybn.17
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.5 OK p1sm1037082ybn.17
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:354 Go ahead p1sm1037082ybn.17
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.0.0 OK 1290167720 p1sm1037082ybn.17
```

i am using class.phpmailer.php file and using $obj.Send() method to send email. ??

thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

PHPMailer has a "debug" flag that you can turn off.

Depending on which version you are using, it could be named `Debug` or `SMTPDebug`. You'll know it when you see it. If necessary, look into the class file to find out the name.

Set that to false and all is well.

Comment: Nice. You're working with this library day-to-day, or perhaps you have some pills that help you remembering long API docs? :) If the latter, here's my address...

Comment: i have put SMTPDebug = 2, is this the cause?

Comment: @pestaa heh, for some reason I remembered this from debugging a SMTP server once :)

Comment: @Pekka, what should i enter to get rid of messages?

Comment: Oh, in that case please don't send your whole cluster to me. :P

Answer (score 10):

As mention above it's the **SMTPDebug** option, just do:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
```

Answer (score 7):

By default it shouldn't generate any output. Make sure it is not wrapped in a print/echo statement/function.

A workaround could be using `ob_start()` at the beginning and `ob_get_clean()` at the end of your mailer script, so that it prevents any output from leaving the buffer.

Comment: ob_start(); $mail->Send(); ob_get_clean(); //works well, thank you!

Comment: maybe instead of ob_get_clean() should be more logical ob_end_clean()

Answer (score 2):

If you are picking the whole config set from the example of the official PHPMailer github page, then just remove/comment out this line:-

```
 $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
```